# Responsive carousel with a custom horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, carousel

I need to create carousel with a custom horizontal scrollbar
Existing solutions suggests carousels with arrow/dots navigation
Maybe anyone faced such a problem and can suggest some solution

Comment: can you show what approach have you tried so far and how your carousel is structured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need an carousel with scroll, you can make a carousel manually and use the property `overflow-x: scroll`.

I made an example, see if is something like that.

Here's the code: https://codepen.io/jvitorfrancisco/pen/BaQdKLG